# Does Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer support FTPS?

Tags: windows-runtime, ftps, background-transfer

I see that Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer does support FTP:

```
ftp://user:password@server/file.txt
```

But does it support FTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, BackgroundTransfer API does not support FTPS.

As mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452979.aspx):

> This feature is ideal for large file download and upload operations using the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. FTP is supported, but only when conducting download operations.